# Are there standardized generic functional interfaces in Java8?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I wonder if and where somebody did the job of defining a set of generic functional interfaces to ease and standardize the usage of lambdas.
I come from C# where the core libraries did the job.

I read about "BiFunction" and found it to be clumsy. Especially when extended to TriFunction etc.

I came up with the following:

```
public interface FI {
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Action<T> {
    void invoke(T arg1);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function0<TResult> {
    TResult invoke();
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function1<Targ1, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function2<Targ1, Targ2, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function3<Targ1, Targ2, Targ3, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2, Targ3 arg3);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function4<Targ1, Targ2, Targ3, Targ4, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2, Targ3 arg3, Targ4 arg4);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function5<Targ1, Targ2, Targ3, Targ4, Targ5, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2, Targ3 arg3, Targ4 arg4, Targ5 arg5);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function6<Targ1, Targ2, Targ3, Targ4, Targ5, Targ6, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2, Targ3 arg3, Targ4 arg4, Targ5 arg5, Targ6 arg6);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function7<Targ1, Targ2, Targ3, Targ4, Targ5, Targ6, Targ7, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2, Targ3 arg3, Targ4 arg4, Targ5 arg5, Targ6 arg6, Targ7 arg7);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function8<Targ1, Targ2, Targ3, Targ4, Targ5, Targ6, Targ7, Targ8, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2, Targ3 arg3, Targ4 arg4, Targ5 arg5, Targ6 arg6, Targ7 arg7, Targ8 atg8);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function9<Targ1, Targ2, Targ3, Targ4, Targ5, Targ6, Targ7, Targ8, Targ9, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2, Targ3 arg3, Targ4 arg4, Targ5 arg5, Targ6 arg6, Targ7 arg7, Targ8 atg8, Targ9 arg9);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function10<Targ1, Targ2, Targ3, Targ4, Targ5, Targ6, Targ7, Targ8, Targ9, Targ10, TResult> {
    TResult invoke(Targ1 arg1, Targ2 arg2, Targ3 arg3, Targ4 arg4, Targ5 arg5, Targ6 arg6, Targ7 arg7, Targ8 atg8, Targ9 arg9, Targ10 arg10);
}

}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the standard Java library exactly like this; the closest are the interfaces in the package `java.util.function`.

Comment: Well ... your `Action` is basically `Consumer`. `Function0` is `Supplier`. `Function1` is `Function`. `Function2` is `BiFunction`. The rest are probably of pretty limited usefulness. If you're writing functions with 10 parameters, there's probably better ways to write it.

Comment: A function with 10 parameters should probably have a class to wrap those values.

Comment: I have written my own TriFunction before but in each case ended up giving it a more specific and meaningful name.

Comment: I agree with 10 parameters being too many. But as a library author one should not impose one's opinions on the library user if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8 Officially only exist 4 types of Functions.

```
  Consumer: Void function
  Function: receive argument return argument
  BiFunction: Receive 2 arguments return argument
  Predicate: receive argument return boolean
```

Here you can see some examples about it.

https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/stream/Functions.java

Comment: Yes, that's what I found.

Comment: Predicate receives 1 argument

Answer (score 2):

javaslang[1] provides `Function0`-`Function8` and even `CheckedFunction0`-`CheckedFunction8`. They provide even additional functionality like 'memoization' and 'currying'.

http://javaslang.io

Answer (score 0):

The closest analogues you'll find are in the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package:

```
interface Function<T,R> { R apply(T t) }

interface Consumer<T> { void accept(T t) }

interface BiFunction<T,U,R> { R apply(T t, U u) }
```

etc. You can define your own, or you may find some in, e.g., [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) or other libraries.